# Randomly Sprout New Patches?

Tags: netlogo, patch

In my model, I'd like to randomly add new patches to my grid.  Is there a simple code that will do that after some amount of time or some threshold? For example, if I get to 25% of my original number of patches, then grow a random number of new patches.  Or if a certain number of ticks pass, then grow a random number of new patches? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `resize-world` command kills everything when it does the resizing. However, you can achieve the same sort of effect by starting with the biggest world you are ever going to use, but only have some of it available. That is, create a `patches-own` variable named something like "can-use?" with `true` for your starting world patches and `false` for the ones that you will use later. Then you can increase the available patches as you want them. If you do this, then instead of referring to `patches` in your code, you can refer to `patches with [can-use?]`.